# Force 2 columns to have unique values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am tying to make a table for related products so products will have a many on many relation.  I want to make sure products van not have a relation with them self.

My table looks like this:

```
ProductID int
RelatedToProductID int
Active bit
```

and has values like this:

```
productID RelatedToProductID Active
1         2                  1
1         3                  1
2         1                  1
2         2                  1
```

but I want to exclude relations like the last one, were a products has a relation to itself.

Does anyone know how to make that possible in ms sql?

Comment: Consider using GUID/UUID

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a `check` constraint to prevent self-relations:

```
alter table YourTable
    add constraint CHK_YourTable_NoSelfRelation
    check (productID <> RelatedToProductID)
```

Comment: Thank you, your a life saver. I have been looking for this for a long time now.

Answer (score 1):

You can add UNIQUE constraint on columns (productID,RelatedToProductID)

```
alter table YourTable add UNIQUE(productID,RelatedToProductID)
```

Answer (score -1):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx):

> C. Creating a unique nonclustered index
>
> The following example creates a unique nonclustered index on the column of the table. The index will enforce uniqueness on the data inserted into the column.

Query:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX AK_ProductId_RelatedToProductId
    ON table (ProductId, RelatedToProductId);
```

See also [Difference Between Unique Index vs Unique Constraint](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/04/26/sql-server-difference-between-unique-index-vs-unique-constraint/)

Comment: I just read this so I'll answer your real question. It was downvoted because you didn't answer the question and gave a bad answer. It's a bad answer because the answer you gave is incorrect to the question being asked.

Answer (score -2):

```
Select ... From Table Where productId <> RelatedToProductId
```